# change datePattern of dijit date textbox on button click

Tags: datepicker, dojo, constraints

I am able to dynamically change some constraints of the Dijit `DateTextBox` but when I try to change the `datePattern`, it just doesn't work. For example:

```
var theDateWidget = dijit.byId(/*RefToDateTextBox*/);

theDateWidget.constraints.max = new Date(); // works fine... :)

theDateWidget.constraints.datePattern = "yyyy"; // does not work, it also harms the DateTimeTextBox widget,  I cannot select any value from drop down anymore
```

I first have a `datePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"` set to the widget on creation and then later in the code I decide to change that pattern to `"yyyy"`

Anyone has any idea how can I change the `datePattern` of `DateTextBox` widget dynamically, say on button click.

Comment: It's should work as defined bellow , which dojo version you're using !
here is sample and it works fine : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BfTXC/287/)

Comment: Well like this it does not work for me, I guess since I am using some kind of generator to create the widget dynamically, but thanks for your reply anyway. I am using Dojo 1.10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a widget's constraints, you should set its 'constraints' attribute. Assuming you only wanted to update the date pattern without affecting other constraints, you'd do:

```
var constraints = theDateWidget.get('constraints');
constraints.datePattern = 'yyyy';
theDateWidget.set('constraints', constraints);
```

Doing this is safer than modifying the internals of widget properties directly, because widgets often need to take additional steps when their properties are updated.

Also, note that `datePattern` is used both for parsing an input value and formatting the widget's value for display. If it's set to an incomplete pattern, like "yyyy", the widget's functionality is going to be severely limited (it will only be able to understand year values, not complete dates).

Comment: Thanks man. This works perfectly, as I expected. I am new to dojo/dijit and that's why I did this mistake. The idea to set the constraints object makes sense now, you saved my day!